# Are there working build instructions or prebuilt binaries of gdal stable >= 2.3.0 with pdfium available for linux x64?

Tags: gdal

I have tried to manually download the latest version of gdal (2.3.0 at time of this post) so that I can compile it on linux x64 (ubuntu 16.04) with the `--with-pdfium` flag enabled to test out GeoPDF to MapBox Vector Tile conversion. After much tinkering I seem to have successfully compiled pdfium with https://github.com/klokantech/pdfium/blob/build/build-lin.sh, but when I go to compile gdal it errors out with `undefined reference to CFDF_Document::CreateNewDoc()`.

Has anyone successfully built gdal 2.3.0 or above with the `--with-pdfium` on linux? Can you link to working instructions? Are there precompiled binaries available?

Edit: I can't get this working so I'm just going to use podofo which is installable from apt-get.

Comment: exact same issue with compilation of GDAL 2.4.4 --with-pdfium on Centos7 ... did anyone manage to find out what is struggling during compilation ?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, by adding the `--without-libtool` flag, the build ends with no errors, and GDAL seems to be working properly. However I don't know about the impact of compiling GDAL without libtool support.